# How to redirect page in javascript without showing variable in url?

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to redirect page with variable through javascript.
I have found `window.location.href = "test.php?variable=" + variabletosend;`
but in this way user can change url and hence values.

Please tell me, how to pass variable to another page through javascript, hidden from user.

Comment: This is not possible. Any JS redirection will be visible to the user because it is a client-, not server-based redirect. You need something like Apache Mod-Rewrite.

Comment: Javascript runs on the user's browser. He can see it ! What you can do is to use button with submit and redirect the url in php.

Comment: maybe try a hidden form  and use jquery to post that form to another page?

Comment: A user will ***always*** be able to modify a request. In case this is supposed to be a security measure: Security through obscurity is not only bad practice, it is outright dangerous. Plain and simple: Use server side session variables to pass data. Also, you might want to read [the OWASP Guide v4](https://www.owasp.org/images/5/52/OWASP_Testing_Guide_v4.pdf), too.

Answer (score 3):

Your entire approach is wrong.

You can never trust a URL from a user, nor prevent the user from seeing the URL to the page.

Instead, you need to write server-side code to return an error if the user tries to access they're not supposed to.

Comment: can you provide some link, how to do that?

Comment: @RaghavGarg: That completely depends on your code and data.  `if (userId is not allowed to access)`

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

1. Instead of GET request, use POST (if you don't want parameters in url)
2. If you want to pass parameter + redirect then, it would be better if you could store those values as session variable.

Comment: Users can still see and modify POST variables.

Comment: As far as I know, nobody can access post variable and due to which they are kind of 'safe". Plus i'm saying to store data in session variable

Comment: But they can simulate (send their own) POST request, hence add there whatever they want.

Comment: Completely wrong;  you can easily see POST variables in the dev tools.

Comment: Unless and until they know what parameter does the api or requested page is requiring.

Answer (score 0):

If you worry about user accessing improper pages of your site you should correclry handle such requests either in server-side running code or using your web-server (IIS, Apache, etc)

Answer (score 0):

You basically want to send the variable to a php page via js.I also had this kind of problems.you should use AJAX request.I know it sounds complex but after you google it this would be easy.In jquery you could use(it would be good to check for syntax error):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'test.php',
                data: { variable : variable },
                success: function(data)
                {
                    alert("success!");
                }
            });
 });
```

Comment: Don't forget to import jquery and also I forgot to mention that variable wont be seen to the users.

Comment: Users can easily see and modify the value in the dev tools.

Comment: That sounds interesting.I would like to know the procedure.

Comment: I guess it will only show http requests and even if it shows ajax calls the how can a user modify it.

Comment: @SLaks Are you online?

Comment: AJAX calls **are** HTTP requests.  And there are myriad ways to modify or replay them; you can edit the code in the debugger, or right-click the request.  You can **never** trust anything that came from the client.

Comment: Yes ajax calls are http request but then they don't give the response as a total html doc but a part of it.@SLaks  after we right click them how do we modify them.

Comment: ajax requests are not a normal http request it is like differentiating syn and tcp packet

Comment: Wrong.  AJAX requests are no different from normal HTTP requests.

Comment: Not exactly different they are http requests but they still differ thats why sometime we call them ajax requests technically they aren't but logically they are.

Comment: But I am not interested in that I am interested in how can I  modify them.

Comment: Lets be more specific:-1)a AJAX request handles the lifecycle of the http request

Comment: Lets be more specific:-1)a AJAX request handles the lifecycle of the http request 2)the header is quite different.

Comment: 3)A normal http request makes synchronous call whereas ajax makes asynchronous calls

Comment: 4)It doesn't returns whole html doc as mentioned above but a xml.

Comment: @SLaks are you online

Comment: @SLaks why aren't you answering.

Comment: @SLaks I saw your profile quite interesting.You have mentioned that you started programming when you were 12 and I started programming when I was 7 and today my age is 12.

Answer (score 0):

```
use this file."jquery.redirect.js"
$("#btn_id").click(function(){
$.redirect(http://localhost/test/test1.php,
      {
       user_name: "khan",
       city : "Meerut",
    country : "country"
      });
});
see=https://github.com/mgalante/jquery.redirect
```

Comment: Please add some explenation to your answer. Posting only code can be confusing.